# Postgresql Unique Index on two columns with null value

Tags: postgresql, unique-index

lets consider simple table

```
addresses_tab
id (SERIAL), user_id (INTEGER) address (VARCHAR)
```

It is possible to generate unique index on two columns:

```
user_id, address
```

but only in case if field address IS NOT NULL

So valid case is:

```
15, 'SOME STREET'
15, NULL
15, 'ANOTHER STREET'
15, NULL
```

but invalid is

```
15, 'SOME STREET'
15, 'SOME STREET'
```

Comment: What's wrong with `create unique index on addresses (user_id, address)`?

Comment: You are right! I didn't noticed that in some address fields I had empty string instead of null value

Comment: Wouldn't a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-partial.html) over the records having adress NOT NULL be sufficient?